# How to change moodle url

Tags: nginx, moodle

I installed moodle on ubuntu server. I successfully installed the moodle using the wizard on `www.example.com`. below are my `moodle.conf` and `config.php`

```
<?php  // Moodle configuration file

unset($CFG);
global $CFG;
$CFG = new stdClass();

$CFG->dbtype    = 'pgsql';
$CFG->dblibrary = 'native';
$CFG->dbhost    = 'localhost';
$CFG->dbname    = 'moodle';
$CFG->dbuser    = 'moodleuser';
$CFG->dbpass    = 'password';
$CFG->prefix    = 'mdl_';
$CFG->dboptions = array (
  'dbpersist' => 0,
  'dbport' => 5432,
  'dbsocket' => '',
);

$CFG->wwwroot   = 'https://www.example.com';
$CFG->dataroot  = '/var/www/moodledata';
$CFG->admin     = 'admin';

$CFG->directorypermissions = 0777;

require_once(__DIR__ . '/lib/setup.php');
```

for nginx `moodle.conf`

```
upstream php-handler {
    server unix:/run/php/php-fpm.sock;
}

server {
        server_name          example.com www.example.com;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload";
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

        resolver_timeout 5s;

        root /var/www/moodle;
        rewrite ^/(.*\.php)(/)(.*)$ /$1?file=/$3 last;

        location ^~ / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$request_uri;
                index index.php index.html index.htm;
 
                location ~ \.php$ {
                        include fastcgi.conf;
                        fastcgi_pass php-handler;
                }
        }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}

server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        server_name          example.com www.example.com;
 
        listen               80 default_server;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot




}
```

my site is running on `example.com`. I want to run it on `example.com/moodle`. When i change the `$CFG->wwwroot` to `example.com/moodle` i get `too_many_redirects` error. how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

The root of your site is `/var/www/moodle;` in your nginx config. That points straight to your moodle code.
One way to change this is to put all your moodle code in another nested folder, ie. `/var/www/moodle/moodle`
Otherwise you can change the root to `/var/www` instead.